# Trigger timer callback

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have a stateful DoFn where I batch elements for a while and then use a timer to trigger a batch flush. Something like:

```py
class BatchToPubSub(DoFn):
    HEAP_STATE_SPEC = ReadModifyWriteStateSpec("events_heap", CDCEventHeapCoder())
    TIMER = TimerSpec("timer", TimeDomain.WATERMARK)

    BATCH_SIZE = 512

    def process(
        self,
        element,
        events_heap_state=DoFn.StateParam(HEAP_STATE_SPEC),
        timer=DoFn.TimerParam(TIMER),
        t=DoFn.TimestampParam,
    ):
        _, event = element
        events_heap = events_heap_state.read() or CDCEventHeap()
        events_heap.push(event)
        self.incoming_count.inc()
        events_heap_state.write(events_heap)

        if len(events_heap) >= self.BATCH_SIZE:
            timer.set(time.time())   # here I want to force timer callback
            # self.expire(...) manual call to callback
        else:
            timer.set(t + Duration(seconds=ALLOWED_LATENESS))
```

What is the best approach to trigger the callback by setting the timer? I've noticed that if set the timer to the current timestamp, the callback never gets triggered.
The other way of doing this is to manually call the callback and I'm fine with this, but I am thinking if it's better to make the timer trigger it?

**Update** add code for timer spec and state spec.

Comment: Are you running a streaming job, and what is the runner you are using? Is the built-int GroupIntoBatches transform suitable for your usecase?

Comment: I run the job in Dataflow and yes, it's a streaming job. GroupIntoBatches won't work for my use case. I use a heap because I need total order of events.

Comment: What windowing and timer functions are you using? Are you able to post more of your pipeline?

Comment: @Cubez I've updated the code snippet. The actual pipeline is really simple, reading from pubsub, decoding to Python dicts and then using this stateful DoFn to batch events and then push them to another sink. We don't use windowing at all.

Comment: Does timer.set(0) work? In your code you are setting a timer to fire at the current timestamp, but you are using a watermark timer. What seems to be occurring is that the timer never fires because the watermark is always behind the current time. So for every new element that comes in before the heap flushes, it sets the timer to a time after the watermark.

Comment: Done some testing and no, the callback is not triggered with `timer.set(0)`. I still have to manually call the callback.